# Object is possibly 'null'. TS2531

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I wanted to use QrReader to scan file according to [[https://github.com/Musawirkhann/react_qrcode_generation_scanner](https://github.com/Musawirkhann/react_qrcode_generation_scanner)

It's writtern by react. But I want to use by tsx.

And there's an error `Object is possibly 'null'.  TS2531` in `qrRef.current.openImageDialog()`

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from 'react'
import QrReader from 'react-qr-reader'

type ScanFileState = {
  scanResultFile: string
  setScanResultFile: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<string>>
  qrRef: React.MutableRefObject<null>
}

const ScanFile: React.FC<ScanFileState> = () => {

  const qrRef = useRef(null)

  const [scanResultFile, setScanResultFile] = useState('')

  const handleErrorFile = (error) => {
    alert(error)
  }
  const handleScanFile = (result) => {
    if (result) {
      setScanResultFile(result)
    }
  }

  const onScanFile = () => {
    qrRef.current.openImageDialog()
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <button type='button' onClick={onScanFile}>Scan Qr Code</button>
      <QrReader ref={qrRef}
        delay={300}
        style={{ width: '100%' }}
        onError={handleErrorFile}
        onScan={handleScanFile}
        legacyMode />
      <h3>Scanned Code: <a href={scanResultFile}>{scanResultFile}</a></h3>
    </div>
  )
}

export default ScanFile
```

I tried using `as`. But didn't work. Also The error changed to `Property 'openImageDialog' does not exist on type 'HTMLButtonElement'.  TS2339`

```
  const onScanFile = () => {
    if (!qrRef) {
      return
    }
    (qrRef.current as HTMLButtonElement).openImageDialog()
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do two things here. First let typescript know that the ref you are  creating is of QrReader:

```
const qrRef = React.useRef<QrReader>(null)
```

Then, since the ref can be null at render startup, use the optional chaining operator while calling `openImageDialog`:

```
qrRef.current?.openImageDialog()
```

You can find more about optional chaining [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining).

Comment: Thank you so much! needed `React.useRef<QrReader>(null)`

Answer (score 1):

This is a much better way

```
const qrRef = useRef<QrReader>(null!)
```

Now you can directly access refs without optional chaining

```
qrRef.current.openImageDialog()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use optional chaining for null check:

```
qrRef?.current?.openImageDialog()
```

which simply translates to (and you can use this also):

```
if(qrRef && qrRef.current) qrRef.current.openImageDialog()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error is because of the line: `const qrRef = useRef(null)` and `qrRef` doesn't change its value until the first render.
Try

```
const onScanFile = () => {
    if (qrRef.current !== null) {
        qrRef.current.openImageDialog()
    }
}
```